# 'int' object not callable al ingresar datos a una BD

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-wtf

estoy haciendo una webapp con flask y wtf_forms y necesito ayuda con un error del tipo 'int' object not callable en una funcion que realiza modificaciones a una base de datos para registrar usuarios:

```
import sqlite3
URL_DB = 'cp13.db'

def accion(instru, datos) -> int:
    "Ejecuta una accion sobre la base de datos"
    try:
        with sqlite3.connect(URL_DB) as con:
            cur = con.cursor()
            res = cur.execute(instru, datos).rowcount()
            if res != 0:
                con.commit()
    except Exception as ex:
        res = 0
        print('Aqui hubo un error al realizar el query que es:  ', ex)

    return res
```

y esto es lo que le paso cuando invoco la funcion:

```
    # Preparar el query
    sql = 'INSERT INTO usuarios(nombre, apellidos, correo, contraseña, fecha_nacimiento, sexo) 
           VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
    # Ejecutar la consulta
    pwd = generate_password_hash(cla)
    res = accion(sql, (nom, ape, ema, pwd, fnac, sex))
```

Este es el formulario flask_wtf:

```
class Registro(FlaskForm):
    nom = TextField('Nombre *', validators=[Length(
        min=1, max=100, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(message='Nombre es requerido')])
    ape = TextField('Apellido *', validators=[Length(
        min=1, max=100, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(message='Apellido es requerido')])
    ema = EmailField('Email *', validators=[Length(
        min=3, max=100, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(message='Email es requerido')])
    cema = EmailField('Confirmar email *', validators=[Length(
        min=3, max=100, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(message='Email es requerido'),
        EqualTo(ema, message='Email y su verificación no corresponden')])
    cla = PasswordField('Clave *', validators=[Length(
        min=5, max=40, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(message='Clave es requerido')])
    ver = PasswordField('Verificación *', validators=[Length(min=5, max=40, message='Longitud fuera de rango'), InputRequired(
        message='Clave es requerido'), EqualTo(cla, message='La clave y su verificación no corresponden')])
    fnac = DateField(
        format="%d-%m-%y", validators=[DataRequired(message='Fecha de nacimiento requerida.')])
    sex = RadioField('Label', choices=[
                     ('M', 'Mujer'), ('H', 'Hombre'), ('P', 'Otro')], default="P")
    btn = SubmitField('Registrar')
```

Y de esta manera obtengo los valores del formulario:

```
nom = escape(request.form['nom'])
ape = escape(request.form['ape'])
ema = escape(request.form['ema'])
cema = escape(request.form['cema'])
cla = escape(request.form['cla'])
ver = escape(request.form['ver'])
fnac = request.form['fnac']
sex = frm.sex.data
```

Agradeceria mucho su ayuda

Comment: el error se generar por hacer, por ejemplo,  `3()` donde estas invocando al método `call` de un número (el cual no tiene). Revisa el valor de todas tus variables, tal vez en una estes haciendo `var()` y el valor de `var` sea un número

Comment: Si, busque el error y puede ocurrir por eso, pero en la función que ejecuta la acción no encuentro que var invoque como función

Comment: podrías poner el error completo?

Comment: Añadí mas información, el error cuando imprimo el exception en consola es:     'int' object is not callable,no se si sea por el tipo de datos que le pase como argumentos a la función

Comment: no has puesto el error completo, porfavoragrega todo lo que sale en la consola, si tienes un `try/except` quitalo y coloca el error entero. Ahí se especifica en que línea ocurre el error

Comment: Ya encontré el error, simplemente no debía invocar .rowcount(), correcto sería .rowcount,  ya que no es un método, es solo un entero, ya funciona